# What Data Structure Does the C# Class "List" Default to?

Tags: c#, list, data-structures

Is it an ArrayList? Or a LinkedList? If I don't specify and run:

```
List<int> x = new List<int>(10);
```

What is the type of list created?

Comment: Did you look at the documentation for that type?  What did it say on the subject?

Comment: The type created is exactly, precisely, `List<int>`. Is this a trick question? :-P

Comment: [Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx#Remarks)

Comment: This question seems to be on the assumption that `List` in C# is just like `List` in Java- an abstract type that can have multiple implementations. It's not. The java Equivalent to C#'s `List` would be `ArrayList`.

Comment: @JeroenMostert There are many ways to implement a list.  It's not a trick question, just a poorly researched one.

Comment: From [MSDN Docu](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx#Remarks): "The List<T> class is the generic equivalent of the ArrayList class. It implements the IList<T> generic interface by using an array whose size is dynamically increased as required."

Comment: @Servy The use of the phrases "default to" and "if I don't specify" makes me think there's a misunderstanding beyond just not knowing how a list is implemented

Comment: @BenAaronson Sure, but that would all still be cleared up by looking at the documentation for the type.

Comment: @BenAaronson An `ArrayList` btw. isn´t `abstract`, so it´s not really similar to Javas `List`.

Comment: @Servy: That was a Socratic question. And also a slightly facetious one, as evidenced by the smiley.

Comment: @HimBromBeere I meant the other way around. C#'s `List` is like Java's `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is in plain english in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx#Remarks):

> The List class is the generic equivalent of the ArrayList class. It implements the IList generic interface by using an array whose size is dynamically increased as required.

Answer (score -1):

List - is a generic collection class. 
It`s not an ArrayList or LinkedList.

```
public class List<T> : IList<T>, ICollection<T>, IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable, IList, ICollection, IReadOnlyList<T>, IReadOnlyCollection<T> { ... }
```

But you can create ArrayList from List

```
var arrayList = new ArrayList(list);
```